# sensorManager.registerListener in a background service

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an Android background service written for a Cordova app, which I want to interact with the accelerometer via the sensorManager.

I feel I'm pretty close, but just not quite there, I think.

For some reason the sensorManager.registerListener doesn't seem to fire the onSensorChanged method - I'm checking the X value every 5 seconds from the MyService (my background service class).

From what I have read it's something to do with needing a handle on the registerListener, but I'm not sure...what or how.

Here's my code (cut down for readability):

```
    class AccelListener implements SensorEventListener
    {

        public AccelListener(Context ctx) {
            mCtx = ctx;
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        }

        public int start() {
             List<Sensor> list = this.sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

            if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
              this.mSensor = list.get(0);
              this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
               } 

            return this.status;
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


            if (this.accuracy >= SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM) {
                this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                this.x = event.values[0];
                this.y = event.values[1];
                this.z = event.values[2];
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyService extends BackgroundService 
    {

        protected JSONObject doWork() {
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
            Context thisContext = getApplicationContext();
            AccelListener objAccel = new AccelListener(thisContext);
            int intAccelReturn = objAccel.start();
            setInterval(function()
            {
                result.put("OUTPUT", objAccel.x);
            },5000);

}
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

O.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem but I think

```
List<Sensor> list = this.sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
  this.mSensor = list.get(0);
  this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
```

can be converted to the simpler

```
this.mSensor = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

Your problem could be that you never call the function `start` (or at least you don't do so in the code you posted).

Can you print the value of `intAccelReturn`. It might give a clue into what is happening. Are you sure your phone actually has an accelerometer? It's good practice to add an `@Override` annotation to the `onSensorChanged` function (that way if there was no function in the super class with that name you will get an error). See [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) on how to create a background service. You don't call `MyService.doWork` either (did you call it in the actual code).

Comment: Damn, I thought you cracked it then!!! - but realised I'd just missed the start() off the posted code - I've edited it in now - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Another Difference between

```
List<Sensor> list= 
this.sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
  this.mSensor = list.get(0);
  this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.mSensor,     
  SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
```

and

```
this.mSensor = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

Is that in the second example the DefaultSensor is referenced and not ANY sensor in the list. Are you sure, that the Sensor instance at index 0 is the one, you want to reference?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Make your class AccelListener a service itself.

```
public class AccelListener extends Service implements SensorEventListener{...}
```

in your initialisation method (startCommand, constructor, intentReceived or whatever you use), make your initialisation :

```
    if (mSensorManager==null){
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    if (mSensorAccelerometer == null){ 
        mSensorAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor. TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
```

then override the onSensorChanged

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check.

1. Is `onSensorChanged` actually being called, but because you have a test for the accuracy it is being discarded? I could imaging that since the UI rate only delivers around 2-3 samples per second that it may not be considered that accurate, but it's good enough to know if you should rotate the screen.
2. Is the device being moved for this test or is it just sitting on your desk? The values are only reported when something changes (the device is moving around) so an idle device should deliver no samples.
3. The screen is off and you don't have a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. If you want the accelerometer to continue to send you samples when the screen turns off you need a partial wake lock to keep the CPU from sleeping (this can be bad for battery life if you don't release the wake lock). It requires `<uses-permission>android.permission.WAKE_LOCK</uses-permission>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Then in your start you'll have to do something like this:

`

```
// Assuming mLock is a class level PowerManager.WakeLock so it can be released later
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)mCtx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

mLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Accel");
mLock.acquire();
```

`